# how can I add audio and video call facility into react native messenger app like facebook messenger?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, videocall

I have an messenger app like facebook where people can sent message one another. but now I want to audio and video call facility, is It possible ? if possible please help me brothers.

Comment: search for information on webrtc